# Javascript - set div display on click - ClassName not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the following function to change whether a div is shown or not, by clicking an image.

```js
function showTxt(elementClass, nr) {
    "use strict";
    if (document.getElementByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.employees{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.employee{
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.employee_img img{
    width: 100%;    
}

.employee_txt{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="employees">
          
        <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee_img">
              <img src="resources/katerina.jpg" alt="katerina">
            </div>
            <div class="employee_txt" id="katerina"></div>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee_img">
              <img src="resources/sindre.jpg" alt="sindre">
            </div>
            <div class="employee_txt" id="sindre"></div>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee_img"  onclick="showTxt(employee_txt, 2)">
              <img src="resources/daniel.jpg" alt="daniel">
            </div>
        
            <div class="employee_txt" id="daniel">
              <p>this is me</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        
 </div>
```

Stack's snippet tool shows the message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: employee_txt is not defined". And I have noe idea why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: because it is not defined.... You have a varaible reference, not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong, it's `getElementsByClassName`, Elements being plural, and you need quotes around the string you're passing in your function call.

```js
function showTxt(elementClass, nr) {
    "use strict";
    if (document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass)[nr].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.employees{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.employee{
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.employee_img img{
    width: 100%;    
}

.employee_txt{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="employees">
  
 <div class="employee">
  <div class="employee_img">
    <img src="resources/katerina.jpg" alt="katerina">
  </div>
  <div class="employee_txt" id="katerina"></div>
 </div> 

 <div class="employee">
  <div class="employee_img">
    <img src="resources/sindre.jpg" alt="sindre">
  </div>
  <div class="employee_txt" id="sindre"></div>
 </div> 

 <div class="employee">
  <div class="employee_img"  onclick="showTxt('employee_txt', 2)">
    <img src="resources/daniel.jpg" alt="daniel">
  </div>

  <div class="employee_txt" id="daniel" style="display:none;">
    <p>this is me</p>
  </div>
 </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
onclick="showTxt(employee_txt, 2)"
```

It is looking for the variable `employee_txt` not a string.

```
onclick="showTxt('employee_txt', 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it

```
<div class="employee_img"  onclick="showTxt('employee_tx', 2)">
              <img src="resources/daniel.jpg" alt="daniel">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function reference of `showTxt` instead of calling the function and assigning its result to the `onClick` handler.

To do so, use this:

```
onClick="showTxt.bind(showTxt, 'employee_txt', 2)"
```

This will return a new function that already has the 2 parameters bound to it so it can just be called as `func()`.

I would also suggest you to use a variable inside of your `showTxt` function to store the result of the `getElementsByClassName(classname)[index]` call.